# How to calculate high and low entries per year?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a sample table like below. I need to calculate 1 Year High/Low on below data.

```
|   id  |        date         |      amt |  
+-------+---------------------+----------+
|      1|2016-03-01 00:00:00.0|   25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-02 00:00:00.0|   26.6861|
|      1|2016-03-03 00:00:00.0|   27.0688|
|      1|2016-03-04 00:00:00.0|   28.8077|
|      1|2016-03-07 00:00:00.0|   29.6904|
|      1|2016-03-08 00:00:00.0|   26.9298|
|      1|2016-03-09 00:00:00.0|   27.2492|
|      1|2016-03-10 00:00:00.0|    26.278|
```

I think I have to do something like below , but Problem with this code is a year can be a leap year too.

```
def days(i : Int) : Long=  i * 86400 
val aggreate = Window
              .partitionBy("id")
              .orderBy(unix_timestamp($"date"))
              .rangeBetween(-days(365),0)
df.select(df("id"),df("date"),df("amt"))
  .withColumn("wk52_high",max("amt") over aggreate) 
  .withColumn("wk52_low",min("amt") over aggreate )

+------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+------------+
|   id  |        date         |      amt |  wk52_high  |  wk52_low   |
+------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+------------+
|      1|2016-03-01 00:00:00.0|   25.7262|      25.7262|     25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-02 00:00:00.0|   26.6861|      26.6861|     25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-03 00:00:00.0|   27.0688|      27.0688|     25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-04 00:00:00.0|   28.8077|      28.8077|     25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-07 00:00:00.0|   29.6904|      29.6904|     25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-08 00:00:00.0|   26.9298|      29.6904|     25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-09 00:00:00.0|   27.2492|      29.6904|     25.7262|
|      1|2016-03-10 00:00:00.0|    26.278|      29.6904|     25.7262|
```

how can i handle the leap year case?

Comment: Can you `show(false)` to include `date` in its full format (and fix the question)?

Answer (score 1):

What I'd suggest is to use [year](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function to partition by (except `portfolio_id`) and `rank` function to calculate `min` (order ascending) and `max` (order descending) over the window spec.

```
val byYearOrderByAmt = Window.partitionBy(year($"date")).orderBy("amt")
scala> inventory.withColumn("rank", rank() over byYearOrderByAmt).show
+---+-------------------+-------+----+
| id|               date|    amt|rank|
+---+-------------------+-------+----+
|  1|2016-03-01 00:00:00|25.7262|   1|
|  2|2016-03-02 00:00:00|26.6861|   2|
+---+-------------------+-------+----+


scala> inventory.withColumn("rank", rank() over byYearOrderByAmt).where($"rank" === 1).show
+---+-------------------+-------+----+
| id|               date|    amt|rank|
+---+-------------------+-------+----+
|  1|2016-03-01 00:00:00|25.7262|   1|
+---+-------------------+-------+----+
```